# Definition of Poincare Section

Tags: definition, dynamical-systems

**Def:** Let $X\subset Y$ with $\phi_t:Y\to Y$ a semiflow. $X$ is called a *Poincaré section* of $\phi_t$ if the first return time $\tau(x):=$inf$\{t>0:\phi_t(x)\in X\}\in\mathbb{R}^+$ for every $x\in X$, with the convention inf$\{\}=+\infty$.

We then define a discrete dynamical system from the map $f:X\to X$ by $f(x)=\phi_{\tau(x)}(x)$.

**Questions:**

1.) I take this definition of a Poincaré section to mean that every point of $X$ eventually returns to $X$ (infinitely often) and the flow must not be parallel along $X$ (otherwise, $\tau(x)=0\notin\mathbb{R}^+$ for every $x\in X$). In another text I have (Strogatz), it says that if $Y$ has dimension $n$, then the Poincaré section $X$ has dimension $n-1$. I'm not sure why this is the true though. Does this follow from the definition above, or is it an extra condition? Why, for example, couldn't you have a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be a Poincaré section?

2.) I'm not sure why $\phi_{\tau(x)}(x)\in X$. $\tau(x)$ is the greatest lower bound of all times $t$ such that $\phi_t(x)\in X$, but why does this mean that $\tau(x)$ is also such a time? It would seem to me that $\tau$ would have to be defined in terms of a strict minimum instead of an infimum.

Comment: For 1) : If $X$ has dimension $d$ and the semi-flow is smooth, then $\varphi ([0,T], X)$ has (locally) dimension $d+1$. if $d<n-1$, then most points won't be in the orbit of $X$, so $X$ cannot be a Poincaré section.

Comment: For 2) : good remark. We should require that for all $x$, $\{t : \varphi_t (x) \in X\}$ be closed. This is the case e.g. if $X$ is closed, or if $\tau$ is bounded from below.

Comment: Re 1), this is an extra condition. Example: Assume $X$ is a Poincaré section for the flow $\phi_t:Y\to Y$ (thus, with codimension $1$), then every $X\times U$ with $U\subseteq Z$ is a Poincaré "section" (without the codimension condition) for the flow $\phi_t\otimes\mathrm{Id}:Y\times Z\to Y\times Z$, $(y,z)\mapsto(\phi_t(y),z)$ whose first return time is $T(x,z)=\tau(x)$ for every $(x,z)$ in $X\times U$. In particular, $X\times\{u\}$ is a Poincaré "section" in $Y\times\mathbb R^k$ for every $u$ in $\mathbb R^k$ and $\mathrm{codim}(X\times\{u\})=\mathrm{codim}(X)+k\ne1$.